# Implement itertools.groupby from scratch

Tags: python, python-itertools

I tried to implement a function, `groupify(S)` that takes in a

```
string S = 'aabbbbccca'
```

and returns

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)]
```

I am aware that we may use Python `itertools.groupby` to do this. However, I am trying to implement this by scratch. I can think of using `deque` to pop an item from the left, but don't know how to write exact code to do it (i.e. how to obtain [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)] from an input S = 'aabbbbccca' using deque.). I appreciate any one's help.

UPDATE: Just figured out one solution myself. I have been struggling with deque.popleft() and later figured out that I need to use a holder to save anything popped out (i..e the popped variable below).

```
# implement groubpy by scratch
# example: given a string 'aabbbbccca' return [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)]
from collections import deque
import unittest
from itertools import groupby

class Solution:
    def implement_groupby(self, s):
        pair = []
        m = deque(s)
        char = s[0]
        count = 0
        while m:
            popped = m.popleft()
            if char == popped:
                count += 1
            else:
                pair.append((char, count))
                char = popped
                count = 1

        pair.append((char, count))
        return pair

    def use_built_in_groupby(self, s):
        pair = []
        for key, group in groupby(s):
            pair.append((key, len(list(group))))

        return pair

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.solution = Solution()
        self.s1 = 'aabbbbcccaa'
        self.s2 = 'abc'

    def expectEqual(self, first, second):
        with self.subTest():
            self.assertEqual(first, second)

    def testImplementGroupby(self):
        self.expectEqual(self.solution.implement_groupby(self.s1), [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 2)])
        self.expectEqual(self.solution.implement_groupby(self.s2), [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)])

    def testBuildInGroupby(self):
        self.expectEqual(self.solution.use_built_in_groupby(self.s1), [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 2)])
        self.expectEqual(self.solution.use_built_in_groupby(self.s2), [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to implement a [run length encodong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) that compresses a string.

Here is a pure Python implementation without using `collections.deque`.

**Given**

A variant of `unique_justseen` from [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def unique_justseen_(s):
    """Return unique characters as seen from a string.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> s = "aabbbbccca"
    >>> unique_justseen_(s)
    'abca'

    """
    hold, result = "", ""

    for x in s:
        if x == hold:
            continue
        hold = x
        result += x

    return result
```

**Code**

```
def run_length_encode(s):
    """Return a list of compressed strings."""
    result = []

    for x in unique_justseen_(s):
        i = 0
        while (i < len(s)) and (x == s[i]):
            i += 1
            #print(x, s, i)
        s = s[i:]        
        result.append((x, i))

    return result
```

**Demo**

```
run_length_encode("aabbbbccca")
# [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)]
```

---

**Details**

We iterate the unique grouped characters `"abca"` via the helper function `unique_justseen_` .  The inner `while` loop counts observed matches with the unique characters.  `s = s[i:]` "shrinks" a copy of the initial string by eliminating each group of repeated characters (you can observe this by uncommenting the `print` statement).  The unique character is packaged with the final incremented value `i` and appended to a resulting list.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the code. It's good to know it is called the run-length encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use deque to pop elements from list in the following manner

```
from collections import deque
d=deque(['4', '3', '2', '1'])
d.pop()
'1'
d.popleft()
'4'
```

In your case

```
d=deque([('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)])
d.popleft()
print(d)
```

OUTPUT:

```
deque([('b', 4), ('c', 3)])
```

Comment: I meant to say how to obtain [('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)] from an input S = 'aabbbbccca' using deque.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
def groupify(some_data):
group_list = {}
for i in list(some_data):
    if i in group_list.keys():
        group_list[i] += 1
    else:
        group_list.update({i: int(1)})
return group_list
```

sample = "aabbbbccca"

print(groupify(sample))

OUTPUT: {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}